# About Call Marut/Call Kolyarut/Call Zelekhut spell

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

Will an inevitable summoned by a Call Marut/Call Kolyarut/Call Zelekhut spell listen to any commands given by the summoner?
For example, if a summoner orders Marut to protect a Lich by killing a paladin who is trying to destroy it, will Marut follow the order even though it goes against his fundamental nature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These spells were printed first in *Planar Handbook*, and reprinted and updated in *Spell Compendium*. Officially, the reprint supercedes the original printing—the *Spell Compendium* versions of the spells are the official versions.

And notably, *Spell Compendium* **removed** lines that specified any kind of restriction on the called inevitable’s behavior: instead of “The task must be in harmony with its lawful object,” (*Planar Handbook* pg. 96), the update just says “You can ask the [inevitable] to perform one duty for you,” (*Spell Compendium* pg. 42).

(*Spell Compendium* also drastically reduced the amount of time the spell gives the inevitable to complete the task, from 5-9 days to just 1 hour.)

So *Spell Compendium* is less explicit than *Planar Handbook* was—but at the end of the day, it says the caster can “ask” the inevitable to do something, and there’s no payment involved. Nothing in the spell indicates that it forces the inevitable to agree to anything asked of it—and that’s not an inherent part of calling spells as it is for summoning spells. Calling spells usually involve some external factor to get the called creature to do what you want—bribes, threats, whatever. *Gate* compels creatures to perform certain services, but that’s an explicit feature of that 9th-level spell.

**That said**, a lich could call a kolyarut or zelekhut and ask for them to do whatever—they aren’t going to be fundamentally opposed to assisting a lich. (A marut, of course, absolutely would be.) Likewise, any of the three would be willing to fight—or kill—a paladin under the right circumstances: lawful-vs-lawful combat is not uncommon, and paladins serve an authority (Good) that inevitables don’t particularly recognize. If a paladin were, say, fleeing to escape punishment from a lich-king whose (evil) laws the paladin did in fact break, a zelekhut would have absolutely no objection to fighting and possibly even killing the paladin. If a marut became involved in a fight between a lich and a paladin with some divine blessing making them immortal, it might regard **both** combatants as **equally** deserving of its ire.

From a mechanical perspective, these spells pretty much suck. *Call marut*, in particular, is worse than *gate* in almost all ways. *Planar ally* and *binding* are much more inconvenient, but ultimately still far more worth preparing or learning than the extremely niche *call kolyarut* and *call zelekhut*.